# How to change windows 10 screenshot target folder if changed accidentally directly to a drive?

Tags: windows, path, screenshot, target, drive

I was trying to change the screenshot target folder(windows+ prtsc) in windows 10 and I found the solution on Google. While I was changing the path , I accidentally choose the path of a drive without selecting a folder and now whenever i take a screenshot they are saving directly to the drive outside the folders but  I want that they should go inside  a separate folder and I am unable to do so. Kindly suggest the way to do that.

The problem here is that earlier they were inside a folder and I have gone through that folder properties and changed the target folder but now they are not inside any folder and are directly inside a drive and I am unable to find that option again

Comment: You found solution on google, so change target folder again, what is your problem?

Comment: The problem here is that earlier they were inside a folder and I have gone through that folder properties and changed the target folder but now they are not inside any folder and are directly inside a drive and I am unable to find that option again. @user2120666